# Dev and Production apps for iOS (with Facebook SDK)

Tags: ios, facebook

I'm building an app which uses Facebook SDK. Since it's already in production I wanted to install two versions on my device (the App Store Version and the Development version).

I followed this [instructions](http://blog.chrismiles.info/2011/04/ios-dev-beta-production-builds.html) and successfully installed two versions of the app, but when trying to Log in using Facebook I got a problem because the development version bundleID (com.company.app.dev) does not matches the registered one on my Facebook App (com.company.app).

[This guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/troubleshooting#sharedappid) shows how to share the same facebook appID between apps. The guide is quite confusing to me. I registered the two bundle ids (com.company.app.dev and com.company.app) and one URL scheme suffix (dev), and modified mi App.plist file to include the `FacebookUrlSchemeSuffix` key.

That lead me into another problem, when I logged into the production app, the callback was opening the development app, because both apps had the same URL callbacks registered (fbxxxx and fbxxxxdev, where xxxx is my facebook app id).

I solved it registering a user-defined build setting that adds the `FacebookUrlSchemeSuffix` when in Build mode and not in Release mode, and also modifying the URL schemes in the App.plist file to append the suffix in the same case.

But this solution seems a bit hacky since it does now follow the Facebook guides. Is there any better solution to this? I think I'm not following the Facebook guide correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is fine. You should have fbxxxx registered as a scheme in your production app, and fbxxxxdev in your dev app, and also add the suffix in your dev app.